# Telerik RadMenuItem IsEnabled not refreshing consistently

Tags: wpf, telerik

My undo menu item is defined like this:

```
<telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Undo"
                 InputGestureText="Ctrl-Z"
                 Command="{Binding UndoCommand}"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedProjectCanUndo}"/>
```

SelectedProjectCanUndo is a bool property on the main view model, which is the DataContext for the main window containing the menu. I call PropertyChanged on the correct property name, and I can see that SelectedProjectCanUndo is called immediately after, on behalf of the binding. And yet the menu item does not refresh consistently. Sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't. I created a small similar "sandbox" application, but everything works fine there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that CanExecute on the command overrides the IsEnabled flag. I got rid of IsEnabled and added a call to CanExecuteChanged on the command, and now it's working.